# Group element of a list in PYTHON

Tags: python

I have a list like this i want to groupe every 2 elements if they have the same string.split('#',1) and string.split('#',2) `

```
list_1 = ['PERSONNE#FAVE#12','PERSONNE#DATE#12','PERSONNE#KIAL#12']
list_2 = ['PERSONNE#FAVE#11','PERSONNE#DATE#10']
sortie_list = list_1 + list_2
```

Output desired: if an element has not a similar string it will be append the out_list

```
out_list= [['PERSONNE#FAVE#12','PERSONNE#FAVE#11'],  ['PERSONNE#DATE#12','PERSONNE#DATE#10'],'PERSONNE#KIAL#12']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itertools.groupby` is the ticket. You just have to remember to sort first.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda x: x.split('#', 2)[0:2]
>>> [list(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted(sortie_list, key=f), key=f)]
[['PERSONNE#DATE#12', 'PERSONNE#DATE#10'], ['PERSONNE#FAVE#12', 'PERSONNE#FAVE#11'], ['PERSONNE#KIAL#12']]
```

Comment: I actually tried this itertools but as you said, I forgot to mention the sorting,
thank you @Chris

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using defaultdict from collections.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sortie_list = list_1 + list_2

out_list = defaultdict(list)

for item in sortie_list:
    first, second, third = item.split("#")
    out_list[first+'#'+second].append(item)

out_list = list(out_list.values())
```

With these inputs:

```
list_1 = ['PERSONNE#FAVE#12','PERSONNE#DATE#12','PERSONNE#KIAL#12']
list_2 = ['PERSONNE#FAVE#11','PERSONNE#DATE#10']
```

The output is:

```
[['PERSONNE#FAVE#12', 'PERSONNE#FAVE#11'], ['PERSONNE#DATE#12', 
'PERSONNE#DATE#10'], 'PERSONNE#KIAL#12']
```